# Set password at first logon in Samba

Tags: linux, ubuntu, samba

I am looking to build an Ubuntu file server for storage of documents, music, movies and more.. for the whole family.

Each member should have their own (password protected) space for their stuff and there should be a (password protected) public folder that each member can access.

**Is there a way to set a default password that has to be changed at first logon in samba?**

If not, is there an alternative that fulfills my needs? *Note that the shares should be mountable (so OwnCloud is not an option).*

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What kind of authentication are you using? Is this Samba server joiinted in a Windows domain or something? How do they change the password today? AFAIK, no, Samba is not in charging of enforcing this.

Comment: 1. Default authentication (smbpasswd) 
2. It is a standalone server
3. I set password for them with smbpasswd

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your additional details the answer is no.

If you want that kind of integration (and I'm assuming your users are on Windows), look up how to turn Samba into a Domain Controller and/or use LDAP to have single-sign on.

Comment: We use a mix for Windows and Ubuntu machines